# PTSD recovery / prefrontal cortex blood flow

Tags: consciousness, brain-training, ptsd

I am studying a case of PTSD where the patient has lost "crispness of consciousness" and is in a zombie-like state often found among soldiers where only programmed behavior is possible.

The patient is recovering and is noticing that the prefrontal cortex is coming online (I assume he is feeling bloodflow to the area) and that the process is noticeably accelerated through exercise. Are there other proven methods besides exercise that accelerate this kind of recovery / blood flow?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you should take a look at this link from Division 12 of the APA:
http://www.div12.org/psychological-treatments/disorders/post-traumatic-stress-disorder/

Comment: I am closing this question as it is based solely on an anecdotal report of someone *claiming* to feel blood flow in their brains.